# Sort .csv in multidimensional arrays

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector, read.csv

I'm trying to read specific values (i.e. values@coordinate XY) from a .csv file and struggle with a proper way to define multidimensional arrays within that .csv.

Here's an example of the form from my .csv file

```
NaN,NaN,1.23,2.34,9.99
1.23,NaN,2.34,3.45,NaN
NaN,NaN,1.23,2.34,9.99
1.23,NaN,2.34,3.45,NaN
1.23,NaN,2.34,3.45,NaN

NaN,NaN,1.23,2.34,9.99
1.23,NaN,2.34,3.45,NaN
NaN,NaN,1.23,2.34,9.99
1.23,NaN,2.34,3.45,NaN
1.23,NaN,2.34,3.45,NaN

NaN,NaN,1.23,2.34,9.99
1.23,NaN,2.34,3.45,NaN
NaN,NaN,1.23,2.34,9.99
1.23,NaN,2.34,3.45,NaN
1.23,NaN,2.34,3.45,NaN

...
```

Ok, in reality, this file becomes very large. You can interpret rows=latitudes and columns=longitudes and thus each block is an hourly measured coordinate map. The blocks usually have the size of row[361] column[720] and time periods can range up to 20 years (=24*365*20 blocks), just to give you an idea of the data size.

To structure this, I thought of scanning through the .csv and define each block as a vector t, which I can access by choosing the desired timestep t=0,1,2,3...

Then, within this block I would like to go to a specific line (i.e. latitude) and define it as a vector longitudeArray.

The outcome shall be a specified value from coordinate XY at time Z.

As you might guess, my coding experience is rather limited and this is why my actual question might be very simple: How can I arrange my vectors in order to be able to call any random value?

This is my code so far (sadly it is not much, cause I don't know how to continue...)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;


int main()
{   
  int longitude, latitude;                //Coordinates used to specify desired value
  int t;                                  //Each array is associated to a specific time t=0,1,2,3... (corresponds to hourly measured data)
  string value;                           

  vector<string> t;                       //Vector of each block
  vector<string> longitudeArray;          //Line of array, i.e. latitude    

  ifstream file("swh.csv");               //Open file
  if (!file.is_open())                    //Check if file is opened, if not 
  print "File could..."
  {
     cout << "File could not open..." << endl;
     return 1;
  }

  while (getline(file, latitude, latitude.empty()))   //Scan .csv (vertically) and delimit every time a white line occurs
  {
     longitudeArray.clear();
     stringstream ss(latitude);

     while(getline(ss,value,',')         //Breaks line into comma delimited fields //Specify line number (i.e. int latitude) here??
     {
        latitudeArray.push_back(value); //Adds each field to the 1D array //Horizontal vector, i.e. latitude
     }
     t.push_back(/*BLOCK*/)              //Adds each block to a distinct vector t
  }
  cout << t(longitudeArray[5])[6] << endl;    //Output:   5th element of longitudeArray in my 6th block

  return 0;
```

}

If you have any hint, especially if there is a better way handling large .csv files, I'd be very grateful.

Ps: C++ is inevitable for this project...

Tüdelüü,
jtotheakob

Comment: If you want to use some STL, I would be inclined to go with a map for the timesteps. You then have random access, rather than linear in a vector. You could then have a 2D array at each location in the map.

Comment: Do you really want to use strings instead of numeric values? You say your file consists of `45'537'984'000` values, which even for floats would be 169GB of data, and for strings much more (roughly 8 times as much in gcc, if SSO kicks in for every string)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: here if stored as a char array, each value will use exactly 4 bytes, while a double generally uses 8, so the size is a poor argument. But I agree with you, the data should be converted to double and NaN to double nan.

Comment: @SergeBallesta True, I thought of using `std::string` as in the code, but `char[4]` is much more memory efficient.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: Old C programmers think in old C-ish ways ;-)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I chose string, because of the NaN-values. I actually want to convert them into numbers eventually for further computation.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, I don't get what you mean by converting "...NaN to double nan." - can I define letters as double, too? Using char is a good advice, I'll adopt it asap.
Btw, my values may consist of up to 10 digits, but double should be fine then, right?

Comment: @anonmess thanks, I'll have to read about that first but sounds very promising!

Comment: Floating point numbers have 3 special values defined: plus inifinity, minus infinity and `NaN` - Not a Number (there are more, but those are most commonly used, [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Formats) for more info). Both [`std::stof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) and [`std::strtof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) recognize it for you, so you can parse all the values using those..

Answer (score 0):

As usual you should first think in terms of data and data usage. Here you have floating point values (that can be NaN) that should be accessible as a 3D *thing* along latitude, longitude and time.

If you can accept simple (integer) indexes, the standard ways in C++ would be raw arrays, `std::array` and `std::vector`. The rule of thumb then says: if the sizes are known at compile time arrays (or `std::array` if you want operation on global arrays) are fine, else go with vectors. And if unsure `std:vector` is your workhorse.

So you will probably end with a `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> data`, that you would use as `data[timeindex][latindex][longindex]`. If everything is static you could use a `double data[NTIMES][NLATS][NLONGS]` that you would access more or less the same way. Beware if the array is large, most compilers will choke if you declare it inside a function (including main), but it could be a global inside one compilation unit (C-ish but still valid in C++).

So read the file line by line, feeding values in your *container*. If you use statically defined arrays just assign each new value in its position, if you use vectors, you can dynamically add new elements with `push_back`.

This is too far from your current code for me to show you more than trivial code.

The static (C-ish) version could contain:

```
#define NTIMES 24*365*20
#define NLATS 361
#define NLONGS 720

double data[NTIMES][NLATS][NLONGS];
...
int time, lat, long;
for(time=0; time<NTIMES; time++) {
    for (lat=0; lat<NLATS; lat++) {
        for (long=0; long<NLONGS; long++) {
            std::cin >> data[time][lat][long];
            for (;;) {
                if (! std::cin) break;
                char c = std::cin.peek();
                if (std::isspace(c) || (c == ',')) std::cin.get();
                else break;
            }
            if (! std::cin) break;
        }
        if (! std::cin) break;
    }
    if (! std::cin) break;
}
if (time != NTIMES) {
    //Not enough values or read error
    ...
}
```

A more dynamic version using vectors could be:

```
int ntimes = 0;
const int nlats=361;      // may be a non compile time values
const int nlongs=720;     // dito

vector<vector<vector<double>>> data;

int lat, long;

for(;;) {
    data.push_back(vector<vector<double>>);
    for(lat=0; lat<nlats; lat++) {
        data[ntimes].push_back(vector<double>(nlongs));
        for(long=0; long<nlongs; long++) {
            std::cin >> data[time][lat][long];
            for (;;) {
                if (! std::cin) break;
                char c = std::cin.peek();
                if (std::isspace(c) || (c == ',')) std::cin.get();
                else break;
            }
            if (! std::cin) break;
        }
        if (! std::cin) break;
    }
    if (! std::cin) break;
    if (lat!=nlats || long!=nlongs) {
        //Not enough values or read error
        ...
    }
    ntimes += 1;
}
```

This code will successfully process NaN converting it the special *not a number* value, but it does not check the number of fields per line. To do that, read a line with `std::getline` and use a `strstream` to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I tried to transfer both versions to my code, but I couldn't make it run. 
Guess my poor coding skills aren't able to see what's obvious to everyone else. Can you name the additional libs I might require? 
For  `std::isspace` I do need `#include <cctype>`, anything else missing which is not mentioned in my code from above?

Can you also explain how `if (std::isspace(c) || (c == ',')) std::cin.get();` works? From what I understand, it will check whether c (which is the input field?) is a whitespace, and if so, the right term becomes automatically "true" because of `||`? What consequence results from that?

At last, `if (! std::cin) break` is used to stop the loop after we reached the specified array[time][lat][long]?

Anyhow, thanks for your response. I really appreciate it and I have now an idea how to define my loops.

Answer (score 0):

Again thank you all for your ideas.
Unfortunately, I was not able to run the script... but my task changed slightly, thus the need to read very large arrays is not required anymore.

However, I've got an idea of how to structure such operations and most probably will transfer it to my new task.

You may close this topic now ;)

Cheers

jtothekaob